# Copy file to another folder using Google cloud storage JSON API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google JSON APIs in my java application to upload/read/delete/copy files in Google Cloud Storage. When I try to copy files from one folder to another folder I get a 404 error.

For example, I have 2 files with the following prefixes -

1. test-bucket/folder1/file1.txt
2. test-bucket/folder2/file2.txt

```
test-bucket
    |--- folder1/
            |------ file1.txt
    |--- folder2/
            |------ file2.txt
```

Here are details about the Google JSON API

```
API Endpoint - https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<source_bucket>/o/folder1/file1.txt/copyTo/b/<destination_bucket>/o/folder2/file2.txt

Method - POST
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question. Include source code and error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved after encoding the file path. For example -

```
String sourceFilePath = "folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt";
String sourceEncodedPath = URLEncoder.encode(filePath, "UTF-8");

String destinationFilePath = "folder1/folder2/folder3/file2.txt";
String destinationEncodedPath = URLEncoder.encode(filePath, "UTF-8");

System.out.println("Source Encoded Path - " + sourceEncodedPath);
System.out.println("Destination Encoded Path - " + destinationEncodedPath);
```

Output =>

```
Source Encoded Path - folder1%2Ffolder2%2Ffolder3%2Ffil1.txt
Destination Encoded Path - folder1%2Ffolder2%2Ffolder3%2Ffil2.txt
```